# Speediest Julia Set "By Hand"

Tags: performance-tuning, fractals, function-compile

While being aware of the built-in command, I would like to show my students how the Julia set is actually generated. The code I came up with is slow, even though I am quite happy with the picture it ultimately creates.

Can you help me with recommending code replacements that would make the image generation speedier?

```
\[Delta]=0.003;
c=-0.04505+0.66142I;
p=#^2+c&;
grayLevels=200;
iter[z_]:=Length[NestWhileList[p,z,Abs[#]<4&,1,grayLevels]]
range=Flatten[Table[a+b I,{a,-1.5,1.5,\[Delta]},{b,-1.3,1.3,\[Delta]}]];
results=Map[{{Re[#],Im[#]},iter[#]}&,range];
cRange=Union[results[[All,2]]];
cMax=Max[cRange];
cMin=Min[cRange];
cGray=Map[GrayLevel[(#-cMin)/(cMax-cMin)]&,cRange];
ListPlot[Table[Cases[results,x_/;x[[2]]==c][[All,1]],{c,cRange}],AspectRatio->Automatic,PlotStyle->cGray,Axes->False,ImageSize->Large,PlotMarkers->{Automatic, Tiny}]
```

[image: Julia set example "by hand"]

Comment: See [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compile/tutorial/Efficiency.html#367166927)

Comment: Ah, thanks, I.M. One issue that seems to hamper the speed of my code is the rendering. In the link you provided, they only graph the result of the backwards iteration of the polynomial. I, however, test each point in the box for how fast it drifts off to infinity, so I need to plot each point with its appropriate color value. Indeed, if I separate "computation" and "rendering" into separate cells, it's the rendering that eats most of the time. I am baffled how the built-in command manages to render so quickly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Plotting a million points is rather slow, instead you can use `Image`. This requires the results in a 2D array, so remove the `Flatten` from the definition of `range`. Something like this:

```
range = Table[a + b I, {a, -1.5, 1.5, δ}, {b, -1.3, 1.3, δ}];
results = Map[iter, range, {2}];
Image[results/grayLevels]
```

That makes the display fast, but the calculation is still slow. `Compile` is a good option here. To keep things simple I've hard coded the values of `c` and `grayLevels` into the compiled function, but you could easily make them input parameters.

This should run in a couple of seconds.

```
iter = Compile[{{z, _Complex}}, 
   Block[{n = 0, x = z, c = -0.04505 + 0.66142 I},
    While[n < 200 && Abs[x] < 4, x = x^2 + c; n++];
    n/200], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];

δ = 0.003;

range = Table[Complex[a, b], {a, -1.5, 1.5, δ}, {b, -1.3, 1.3, δ}];

Image[iter[range]]
```

If you want it really fast the new LLVM compiler does a good job. This is quick enough to put in a `Manipulate` and vary the `c` parameter in real time.

```
cf = FunctionCompile[
  FunctionDeclaration[escapetime, 
   Typed[{"Complex128", "Complex128"} -> "Integer64"]@Function[{z, c},
     Block[{n = 0, x = z},
      While[n < 200 && Abs[x] < 4, x = x^2 + c; n++];
      n]]],
   Function[{Typed[n, "Integer64"], Typed[c, "Complex128"]},
   Table[escapetime[Complex[a, b], c]/200.0,
    {a, -1.5, 1.5, 3.0/n}, {b, -1.5, 1.5, 3.0/n}]]]

Manipulate[
 Image[cf[250, Complex @@ pt]],
 {{pt, {-0.04505, 0.66142}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Darn, can't upvote a second time.

Comment: The "image" one is still high level enough to be easily understandable without rigorous study of the manual, but it runs in about 0.6 seconds on my computer. It's PERFECT!

Comment: +1 for the `FunctionCompile` showcase! However on my computer (win10+M13.0), `cf` performs [slightly worse](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/a0ab046e-fde4-49a5-baf7-f11661b29006) than `iter` when I set options `Parallelization->True, RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}, RuntimeOptions->"Speed", CompilationTarget->"C"`. Does `FunctionCompile` in current version really have performance advantage over the old `Compile` in certain cases?

Comment: @Silvia, I think I would expect broadly similar performance, at least for simple calculations like this. In my view the main advantage of `FunctionCompile` right now is that it works out of the box without needing to install a separate compiler.

Comment: ``Parallel`ParallelTable`` instead of `Table` inside `FunctionCompile` seems to give some extra boost.