# How can CompiledCodeFunctions be optimized and parallelized?

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, random, compile

#### Fast generation of random variates as test case

The earlier question ([195435](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/195435/764)) about performance tuning with regard to fast generation of random variates for a gamma distribution  has stirred my curiosity and below I am using slightly simpler code from the 3rd ed. of Numerical Recipes ([Normaldev](https://github.com/blackstonep/Numerical-Recipes/blob/master/deviates.h)) to test different versions of a numerical routine to generate random variates for a normal distribution.

#### Different Implementations

The following implementations use the same core *body*, but differ with regard to the way a function is declared in Mathematica:

- `normaldev` is an uncompiled implementation
- `normaldevC` uses `Compile` with `CompilationTarget → "C"`
- `normaldevCLP` uses `Compile` as above, but adds *listablility* and *parallelization*
- `normaldevLLVM` finally uses the new compiler and `FunctionCompile`

**Code** (`` `body` `` has been escaped as`` \`body\` `` ):

```
{ normaldev, normaldevC, normaldevCLP, normaldevLLVM } = With[
    {
      funcBody = "
                While[ cond,
                    u = RandomReal[];
                    v = 1.7156 * (RandomReal[] - 0.5);
                    x = u -0.449871;
                    y = Abs[v] + 0.386595;
                    q = x*x + y *(0.19600*y - 0.25482 * x);
                    If[ q > 0.27597 && ( q > 0.27846 || v*v > -4. * Log[u] * u * u ), cond = True, cond = False ]
                ];
                mu + sig * v/u"
    },
    Module[
        { normaldev, normaldevC, normaldevCLP, normaldevLLVM }
        ,
        normaldev = StringTemplate["
        Function[ {mu, sig },
            Module[
                {
                    u = 1.0,
                    v = 1.0,
                    x = 1.0,
                    y = 1.0,
                    q = 1.0,
                    cond = True
                }
                ,
                \`body\`
            ]
        ]"
        ];
        normaldevC = StringTemplate["
        Compile[ { { mu, _Real }, { sig, _Real } },
            Module[
                {
                    u = 1.0,
                    v = 1.0,
                    x = 1.0,
                    y = 1.0,
                    q = 1.0,
                    cond = True
                }
                ,
                \`body\`
            ],
            CompilationTarget -> \"C\"
        ]"
        ];
        normaldevCLP = StringTemplate["
        Compile[ { { mu, _Real }, { sig, _Real } },
            Module[
                {
                    u = 1.0,
                    v = 1.0,
                    x = 1.0,
                    y = 1.0,
                    q = 1.0,
                    cond = True
                }
                ,
                \`body\`
            ],
            CompilationTarget -> \"C\",
            RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
            Parallelization -> True
        ]"
        ];
        normaldevLLVM = StringTemplate["
        FunctionCompile[
            Function[
                {
                    Typed[ mu,  \"Real64\" ],
                    Typed[ sig, \"Real64\" ]
                }
                ,
                Module[
                    {
                        Typed[ u,    \"Real64\"  ] = 1.0,
                        Typed[ v,    \"Real64\"  ] = 1.0,
                        Typed[ x,    \"Real64\"  ] = 1.0,
                        Typed[ y,    \"Real64\"  ] = 1.0,
                        Typed[ q,    \"Real64\"  ] = 1.0,
                        Typed[ cond, \"Boolean\" ] = True
                    }
                    ,
                    \`body\`
                ]
            ],
            CompilerOptions -> {
                \"AbortHandling\" -> False,
                \"LLVMOptimization\" -> \"ClangOptimization\"[3]
            }
        ]"
        ];
        Map[ ToExpression @ TemplateApply[ #, <| "body" -> funcBody |>]&, { normaldev, normaldevC, normaldevCLP, normaldevLLVM } ]
    ]
];
```

#### Performance evaluation

Using [`RepeatedTiming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RepeatedTiming.html) we can compare run times for these implementations, which I have sorted below from slowest to fastest.

```
RepeatedTiming @ Through[ {Mean, StandardDeviation}@ Table[ normaldev[0.,1.], {1000000}] ]
(* {0.535271,{-0.00048065,1.00115}} *)

RepeatedTiming @ Through[ {Mean, StandardDeviation}@ Table[ normaldevLLVM[0., 1.], {1000000}] ]
(* {0.199849,{0.00011759,1.00026}} *)

RepeatedTiming @ Through[ {Mean, StandardDeviation}@ Table[ normaldevC[0.,1.], {1000000}] ]
(* {0.18677,{-0.00244043,0.998699}} *)

With[ { args =  Transpose @ ConstantArray[{0.0,1.0},1000000]},
    RepeatedTiming @ Through[ {Mean, StandardDeviation}@ ( normaldevCLP @@ args )]
]
(* {0.119437,{0.000838859,0.999507}} *)
```

#### Questions

1. What would be the recommended implementation for the `LLVM` version if speed is the main goal, e.g., setting options, using `` Native`Random `` instead of `RandomReal`?
2. How can the benefits of *listability* and *parallelization* be obtained for `Compiled CodeFunction`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general, the weak spots of interpreted languages are loop constructs and function calls. So I'd suggest to push also the `Table` into the compiled code to generate many random numbers at once.

But the weakness of `normaldevCLP` lies at another point: You first generate a constant array of means and standard deviations. Then you send all this data to the library function. This is two real numbers for each real number that you want to generate. You can avoid this by using

```
normaldevCLP2 = StringTemplate["
        Compile[ { { mu, _Real }, { sig, _Real }, { n, _Integer } },
            Table[
                Module[
                    {
                        u = 1.0,
                        v = 1.0,
                        x = 1.0,
                        y = 1.0,
                        q = 1.0,
                        cond = True
                    },
                    `body`
                ]
            ,{i,1,n}],
            CompilationTarget -> \"C\",
            RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
            Parallelization -> True,
            RuntimeOptions -> \"Speed\"
        ]"];
```

On a 8-core machine for example, you would invoke the compiled function later like this:

```
n = 1000000;
\[Mu] = 0.;
\[Sigma] = 1.;
AdevCLP2 = normaldevCLP2[\[Mu], \[Sigma], ConstantArray[Quotient[n, 8], 8]];
```

On my machine, this yields a 2.5-fold speedup compared to

```
AdevCLP = normaldevCLP[ConstantArray[\[Mu], n], ConstantArray[\[Sigma], n]]
```

"What would be the recommended implementation for the LLVM version if speed is the main goal [...] ?"

I'd recommend not to use `FunctionCompile` at all. IMHO, it is completely ill-designed, in particular when you compare its clunky syntax with the ease of use of numba + numpy in Python. And I have not seen any example, yet, where `FunctionCompile`'s performance was comparable to <s>`Compile`</s> LibraryLink. The only advantage of `FunctionCompile` seems to be that it allows for way more data types.
And, btw., what the heck is the point of wrapping options of LLVM with an additional abstract layer like

```
 \"LLVMOptimization\" -> \"ClangOptimization\"[3]
```

?

This is just inflexible and unmaintainable. Why not simply using the approach of `CreateLibrary` by just sending the string(s) of compiler options directly to the compiler like, e.g.,

```
"CompileOptions" -> {
  , "-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -fopenmp-simd"
  , "-Ofast"
  , "-flto"
  }
```

?

If you really look for performance, then better use the good ol' LibraryLink. It's syntax is awful, but one gets used to it.
Here some example code to generate normally distributed numbers with the C++ standard library and OpenMP for parallelization:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];

Module[{lib, file, name},
 
    name = "normalLibraryLink";
 
    Print["Compiling " <> name <> "..."];
 
    file = Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, name <> ".cpp"}],
   "
#include\"WolframLibrary.h\"

#include <omp.h>
#include <random>

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int " <> name <> 
    "(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res)
{
    // Grab the input arguments.
    mreal mu           = MArgument_getReal(Args[0]);
    mreal sigma        = MArgument_getReal(Args[1]);
    MTensor A          = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[2]);
    mint  thread_count = MArgument_getInteger(Args[3]);

    // Using OpenMP for parallelization.
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads( thread_count )
    {
        // Slow, but truely random number generator for seeding.
        std::random_device r;

        // std::random_device generates 32-bit numbers, so we should use two of them to seed a 64-bit random number engine.
        std::seed_seq seed { r(), r() };

        // A fast pseudorandom number generator, seeded by a random number.
        // 64-bit Mersenne Twister by Matsumoto and Nishimura, 2000
        std::mt19937_64 random_engine ( seed );

        std::normal_distribution<mreal> dist (mu, sigma);

        // Gamma distribution is available by
        // std::gamma_distribution<mreal> dist (alpha, beta);
        // See https://cplusplus.com/reference/random/ for further random distributions.

        // Compute the data range [i_begin,i_end[ for this thread.
        const mint n       = libData->MTensor_getDimensions(A)[0];  
        const mint thread  = omp_get_thread_num();
        const mint i_begin = (n / thread_count) * (thread  ) + (n % \ thread_count * (thread  )) / thread_count;
        const mint i_end   = (n / thread_count) * (thread+1) + (n % \ thread_count * (thread+1)) / thread_count;

        // Get the pointer to the start of shared buffer supplied by the tensor argument.
        mreal * a = libData->MTensor_getRealData(A);

        // Fill the range [i_begin,i_end[ of a with random numbers drawn from the distribution dist.
        for( mint i = i_begin; i < i_end; ++i )
        {
            a[i] = dist( random_engine );
        }
    }

    // Tell the library that it has to let go A.
    libData->MTensor_disown(A);

    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}",
   "Text"
    ];
 
 lib = CreateLibrary[{file}, name
   , "TargetDirectory" -> $TemporaryDirectory
   , "ShellOutputFunction" -> Print
   , "CompileOptions" -> {
     "-Wall"
     , "-Wextra"
     , "-Wno-unused-parameter"
     , "-mmacosx-version-min=12.0"
     , "-std=c++11"
     , "-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -fopenmp-simd"
     , "-Ofast"
     , "-flto"
     , "-mcpu=apple-m1"
     , "-mtune=native"
     }
   , "LinkerOptions" -> {"-lm", "-ldl", "-lomp"}
   , "IncludeDirectories" -> {"/opt/local/include/libomp"}
   , "LibraryDirectories" -> {"/opt/local/lib/libomp"}
   (*,"ShellCommandFunction"\[Rule]Print*)
   , "ShellOutputFunction" -> Print
    ];
    Print["Compilation done."];
    
    normalLibraryLink = LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, name, 
      {
        Real,                 (*mu*)
        Real,                 (*sigma*)
        {Real, 1, "Shared"},  (*vector A; passed by reference. Caution: A gets modified!*)
        Integer               (*thread_count*)
      },
      "Void"                  (*no return value*)
    ]
 ]
```

You can run it by first letting *Mathematica* allocate some array

```
a = ConstantArray[0., n];
```

Then you invoke `normalLibraryLink` to fill it with random numbers, using 8 threads:

```
normalLibraryLink[0., 1., a, 8]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> 0.00177217

The advantage is that the array `a` is passed as `"Shared"`, which means "by reference". So the library can modify the array directly without any allocations or copy operations. You can fill the array `a`; do something with the random numbers; and then refill the same array again. On my machine this is six times faster than `AdevCLP2` and 130 times faster than `AdevLLVM`.

The compile options are selected for macos on an Apple M1 processor and with OpenMP installed via Macports. Of course, you have to adapt them appropriately for other platforms.

Comment: "And I have not seen any example, yet, where FunctionCompile's performance was comparable to Compile. " Well, then you've missed recent examples using `FunctionCompile` in this site e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270431/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/264714/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261329/1871 I agree as an EXPERIMENTAL function it may not be ready for serious work, but perhaps it's time to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Really interesting. I know that `FunctionCompile` is experimental. Nonetheless I do not really see where this project is heading.

Comment: Though I don't share the same idea about `FunctionCompile`, I really appreciate the nice demonstration of LibraryLink! (+1)

Comment: (continue..) I actually had the same thought as OP before, but Simon's post (the one mentioned in @xzczd 's comment) convinced me to give it a try. I think the new compiler is still in very early rapid evolving phase, even it's design might change in the future. Also I think the "clunky syntax" will not be a permanent problem -- maybe after the compiler is stable, people (either WRI or our community) could take time to shield that from users through an abstract layer (maybe a C-like DSL?).

Comment: (continue..) Another observation (see the `cf` function in my post mentioned in @xzczd 's comment above): Maybe just me illusion or misunderstanding of the underlying mechanism, but it feels like the interface provided by `FunctionCompile` is lighter than the one provided by LibraryLink, which I think is the reason my `cf` is slightly faster than @jacob-akkerboom 's solution. (*Or is it?*)

Comment: +1 Thank you, Henrik, for a very helpful post. It would be nice top have a comparable way to put a `FunctionCompile` version against this, which has a parallelized `Table` (or similar looping constructs) inside. So far,  I had some difficulty building a vectorized version with `FunctionCompile` and things like ``Parallel`Table`` seem a bit hard to find in the documentation.

Comment: Hi @Silvia, thank you for your feedback. I have the tendency to be a bit harsh at times.  Sorry to anybody who feels offended by that. "Also I think the "clunky syntax" will not be a permanent problem" Now I see what you mean. I have not though of that before. Nonetheless, `FunctionCompile` feels to me neither like _Mathematica_ nor like _C_. I find that a bit weird.

Comment: Anyways, I appreciate that Wolfram Research invests ressources into a better compilation interface. `Compile` is often convenient, but it has some severe performance problems (e.g., because it does not feature pass by reference) and limitations (only one return value). And I myself had my problems with getting used to LibraryLink. IMHO, Szabolcs' `"LTemplate`" ` package follows a much better ansatz (on top of LibraryLink).

Comment: With regard to @jacob-akkerboom 's solution: I think the issue there is the use of `libData->MTensor_setReal(tensor, pos, 1)`. There might be several potential reasons why that matters: (i) The C-style array `pos` decays into a pointer, meaning additional indirection. This can be avoided by grabing the raw pointer once with `libData->MTensor_getReal` and then use normal indexing.

Comment: (ii) Looking into WolframLibrary.h, I see that `MTensor_setReal` is  a function pointer in the pointer to the struct `libData`. So at least one additional indirection per function call (although the compiler might be clever enough to prevent this).

Comment: (iii) I'd guess that `libData->MTensor_setReal` incoporates a bound check to prevent segfault. Using a raw pointer also deactivates this.

Comment: Hi Henrik, with no doubt you are a far more expert than me regarding high performance programming and compiling techniques. I have learnt a lot from your posts on this site many times. As an ordinary user who is not familiar with C as much as with WL, I'm really holding my breath to wish and see what this brand new compiler will offer. Currently I think the lack-of-documentation might be one of the biggest issue. I just hope WRI ship a manual soon! Thank you very much again for having this discussion.

Comment: Regarding bound check, I think `FunctionCompile` also has similar things, as I see explicit  ``Native`UncheckedBlock`` used in source files which looks like triggering different IR generated.

Comment: Hm. I think the bound checks are already deactivated by `ToRawPointer` (or by ``Array`GetData``). There is a simple experiment for that: Call your function `cf2` on a $10000 \times 10000$ array `mat`, but with `cf2[mat, 20000]`. This entails write access to a part of the memory where it is unlikely that the process has write priviledges. At least my machine reacts with a kernel quit (as it should in such a case).

Comment: I see what you meant. I think ``Native`UncheckedBlock`` does more than that. Although I don't really know anything about LLVM IR, it seems with v.s. without it, the IR emitted will be different, for example `% var72 = tail call { i64, i1 } @llvm.smul.with.overflow.i64(i64 % var2, i64 % var2)` v.s. `% var72 = mul i64 % var2, % var2`. I'm on the way home right now. I'll try to put a self-contained example when I got home. I learnt some undocumented tools in the new compiler from Wolfram Summer School. They are super handy and it's a shame they haven't been documented.

Comment: That looks as if integer overflow checks get deactivated by `Native`UncheckedBlock` in this case. One of the things that the compiler option `"-Ofast"` will enforce.